# Deploying SpringBoot (rest services) war via IntelliJ on Tomcat gives 404's

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, intellij-idea, war

Starting a small SpringBoot application by running the application (directly), the REST service localhost:8080/xyz/a gives a correct JSON result.

Via IntelliJ I configured a Tomcat server. I added this WAR with a context root of '/contextroot'. So I expected the URL REST to be localhost:8080/contextroot/xyz/a. This keeps on getting 404 errors.

1. **Can you help me getting the right configuration or URL?**
2. Is there a way to see which URL's are mapped from the controller to the URL's? Or: how can I solve these mapping issues more easily (from Tomcat)?

In the Maven Pom.xml I have:

```
<groupId>nl.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>contextroot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>contextroot</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

The  within  is also contextroot.

Comment: can u check the url of context path(<Context path=" "/>) in server.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jonhib - thank you for helping.

The problem was the way I deployed a SpringBoot (jar) application as a WAR.

Take these 3 steps to change a SpringBoot standard application into a deployable (old fashioned) WAR. This is needed because I deploy it together with a Angular4 application.

Step 1 - Change the standard SpringBoot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application .class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

2. Change the target of the building process from 'jar' into a 'war'.

   <packaging>war</packaging>
3. Add a new dependency into the pom.xml maven file:

   <dependencies>
       ... 
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       ...
   </dependencies>